# dsmod user pwd fails in Powershell script with parameter is incorrect

Tags: powershell-2.0

Does anyone know why the following line in a PS script would fail:

```
dsmod user $dn -pwd $password -mustchpwd no
```

I have verified that $dn is valid and $password complies with history and complexity requirements. $password does not contain any un-escaped illegal characters.

Here is what makes this strange:

- The same exact command (with variables substituted) works from an
  interactive PS terminal
- Another dsmod is called immediately next in the script to enable the identity: e.g. `dsmod user $dn -disabled no`. This works without issue, so I know the $dn variable is valid.
- The same exact command, as written, works in another script whose only purpose is to reset the password.
- This works on some of our client systems, but not on all.

When this is executed in the script, PS returns:
dsmod failed:The parameter is incorrect.

Any thoughts would be appreciated. Incidentally, if this helps, the script is executing via a server-less bind with the actual domain controller.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

As you've tagged this with `powershell`, I'm a bit puzzled as to why you're not using the `Set-ADUser` and `set-adaccountpassword` cmdlets.

```
Set-ADAccountPassword –Identity $dn -Reset -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $password –Force);
Set-ADUser -Identity $dn -ChangePasswordAtNextLogon;
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a case wherein the context account that the PowerShell script was executing did not have enough elevated permissions to perform the action. Elevating the account to the Administrators group eliminated the behavior.